# Why is there a significant difference in ssh connection speed and stability between my Windows PC and my Macbook?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ssh

I am not sure how to phrase this question well, but I noticed that connecting to a remote machine through ssh, my M2 Macbook Air can connect instantly after turning on from sleep. My Windows PC takes atleast 5 minutes or so until it is able to ssh.

Note that the internet on both the devices is working, and both devices have the permission to connect to the remote machine.

The specs of the machines:

- **Windows PC**: ROG Strix G17 with Ryzen 9 6900HX, RTX 3060 (140W), 16 GB DDR5 RAM, MediaTek Wi-Fi 6E MT7922 160MHz Wireless LAN Card
- **Macbook Air**: M2 chip, 16GB RAM

My Windows PC's OS is Windows 11. I also have WSL2 installed.

How do I **diagnose** this issue? I want to know what is causing this issue. I will add relevant terminal command outputs to the question.

Edit:

Got this as an output with the command: ssh -v

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\*****/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\*****/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *****
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to ***** [*****] port 22.
debug1: connect to address ***** port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host ***** port 22: Connection timed out
```

Output of ssh -vvv:

```
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: send - WSASend() ERROR:10054, io:000001DF88072050
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from 65001 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from 65001 to 850
PS C:\Users\****> ssh -vvv ****@********
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug3: lookup_sid: local user name is same as machine name
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\****/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\****/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for ****
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname **** is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> 'C:\\Users\\****/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> 'C:\\Users\\****/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to **** [****] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:0000028C5FB15B10
debug1: connect to address ***** port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host ****** port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: What happens on Windows if you try to SSH during these 5 minutes after sleep?

Comment: I get: port 22: Connection timed out error

Comment: Which SSH software do you use on Windows? If it has detailed tracing, the log could help.

Comment: I think its OpenSSH. Saw this: C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe

Comment: This is the Windows adaptation of OpenSSH. See the article [Enable Debugging Mode in SSH to Troubleshoot Connectivity Issues](https://www.tecmint.com/enable-debugging-mode-in-ssh/). It might be enough to start with `ssh -v`. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc I got to replicate the problem. Have posted the logs on to the question

Comment: It seems that you cannot connect to the server. Try to disable temporarily the firewall. Try also to ping the server during these 5 minutes. Do you use a VPN? If no indication is found, run `ssh -vvv` and include the log.

Comment: @harrymc I indeed have a Private VPN on my Windows Machine, my Macbook AIr and the remote machine. I have posted the output of ssh -vvv above

Comment: My guess is that there is a problem with the VPN upon waking from sleep. If the VPN relies on a continuous internet connection, it may become disconnected during the sleep. Try upon wake to disable and enable the VPN, to see if this works faster. Which VPN is it?

Comment: @harrymc The closing and opening of the VPN didn't work. The VPN I am using across all three machines is ZeroTier. How is there no problems on MacOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be running into the problem described in the Github
bug-report from April
[ZeroTier having issues reconnecting after Windows sleep/hibernate #1958](https://github.com/zerotier/ZeroTierOne/issues/1958):

> ZeroTier One is having issues reconnecting to networks following a system suspend (sleep or hibernate). When the system is first restored, attempting to connect to any machine on a ZeroTier network does not work. Pinging the machine results in a timeout (console output below).

It seems like your version is behaving better, as it manages still
to reconnect after 5 minutes.

Note that the only workaround in that big-report was to "install
ZeroTier 1.10.1 where this issue almost doesn't exist".
However, this seems to mean that the problem still exists in this
version, although it has a lesser effect.

I suggest to put up a new bug-report with the problem, as it doesn't
seem to be a problem that you can solve yourself, beside looking for
an earlier version that doesn't have it.

Comment: Thanks. Will create a bug report for that. This was a particularly tricky issue to investage